# Epsilon Delta proof of $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2|y|}{x^2+y^2} \text{ for } (x,y) \neq (0,0)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

I'm trying to learn the epsilon delta proof.

Given

$$f(x,y) = \frac{x^2|y|}{x^2+y^2} \text{ for } (x,y) \neq (0,0)$$

I want an epsilon delta proof to see that $f$ is continuous.

I have seen this proof on the internet for $\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$ , but I don't quite understand it.

> Let $\epsilon>0$. Take $\delta:=\epsilon$
>
> If $\vert \textbf{x} \vert < \delta$, then $|y| < \delta$ (where
>   $\textbf{x}=(x,y)$). Therefore:
>
> $\displaystyle |f(x,y)| =\frac{|x^2y|}{|x^2+y^2|}< |y|<\epsilon$

As far as I know, an $(\epsilon, \delta)$ proof is structured like this:

Step $0$: Let $\epsilon > 0$

Step $1$: We try to simplify $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$

Step $2$: We try to find a $\delta$, so that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$ is $< \epsilon$

Step $3$: Summarize: Let $\epsilon > 0$. With $\delta$ we can follow, that for all $x$ it holds that $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \delta \leq \epsilon$

I don't see how that above is a full proof.

What about $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$? Why do we only say $|f(x,y)| =\frac{|x^2y|}{|x^2+y^2|}$ and how do we know what $\delta$ we should take? (In this case he took $\delta := \epsilon)$ Could we have used $\delta = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon$ instead?

Comment: Because $f(0, 0)$ is $0$ in this case. Hence, $|f(x,y) - f(0.0)|$ is basically simplified to $|f(x, y)|$.

Comment: @PythonSage But why do we use $f(0,0)$ if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$? Shouldn't it be $\frac{x^2 |y|}{x^2 + y^2} - \frac{x_0^2 |y_0|}{x_0^2 + y_0^2}$?

Comment: Yes. If you are trying to check continuity around an arbitrary point $(x_0, y_0)$, you are absolutely correct. That would be the case.  

We can easily prove it for an arbitrary point $(x_0, y_0) \ne 0$ that the function $f$ is continuous. My comment presumed that we would only be interested in investigating continuity around $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something is missing when defining the function. i.e.

$f(x,y)=$ $\begin{cases}\frac{x^2|y|}{x^2+y^2} \text{ for } (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\0  \text{ for } (x,y) = (0,0) \end{cases}$.

Then you can proceed.

Let $\epsilon\gt0$.

Observe that $|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|=|f(x,y)|=\frac{|x^2||y|}{|x^2+y^2|}\lt \frac{|x^2||y|}{|x^2|}\lt|y|$

Let $\epsilon=\delta$.

Suppose $|(x,y)-(0,0)|=|\sqrt{x^2+y^2}|\lt\delta \implies |x|,|y|\lt\delta$.

So  $|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|=\frac{|x^2||y|}{|x^2+y^2|}\lt |y|\lt\delta=\epsilon $.

for the part can't I use $\delta=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$. Yes of course you can. In fact you can use any $\delta\lt\epsilon$.